# Python tkinter: How do I make a shape that has it's fill covered by objects, but not it's outline?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am working on a small assignment that includes building an image using as few objects as possible.

I have this project complete, but I had to use one rectangle to give it's dark grey shade behind four circles, and another rectangle in the same spot just for it's outline. Is there a way to make this one single rectangle, while preserving how it looks now?

Long story short, I want the variables 'rectangle_back' and 'rectangle_outline' to be one rectangle, with the 'rectangle_back' fill to be partially covered (how it is now) and the 'rectangle_outline' outline to remain above the circles which are covering 'rectangle_back'. Can this be done? If so, how?

Image: [image]

Code:

```
# File: farmer_john_field
# Author: eluzibur / Elijah Cherry
# Purpose: draw <image>, and calculate area of dark section

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import math

def main():
    root = Tk()
    win = Canvas(root, width = 500, height = 500)
    win.grid()

# point a = 200,200
# point b = 300,200
# point c = 300,300
# point d = 200,300

    # rectangle to fill rear area
    rectangle_back = win.create_rectangle (200,200,  300,300, fill="gray")

    # circles will be placed by top left corner and bottom right corner
    circle_a = win.create_oval (200-50, 200-50,   200+50, 200+50, fill="white")
    #                           a  xtl, a  ytl    a  xbr  a  ybr
    circle_b = win.create_oval (300-50, 200-50,   300+50, 200+50, fill="white")
    #                           b  xtl, b  ytl    b  xbr  b  ybr
    circle_c = win.create_oval (300-50, 300-50,   300+50, 300+50, fill="white")
    #                           c  xtl, c  ytl    c  xbr  c  ybr
    circle_d = win.create_oval (200-50, 300-50,   200+50, 300+50, fill="white")
    #                           d  xtl, d  ytl    d  xbr  d  ybr

    # rectangle outline
    rectangle_outline = win.create_rectangle (200,200,  300,300, outline="gray")

    # texts (labels for points a b c d)
    text_a = win.create_text (200,200, anchor="se", text="A", fill="black")
    text_b = win.create_text (300,200, anchor="sw", text="B", fill="black")
    text_c = win.create_text (300,300, anchor="nw", text="C", fill="black")
    text_d = win.create_text (200,300, anchor="ne", text="D", fill="black")

    # collect length information
    length = float(input("Enter length of one side of the square ABCD: "))
    radius = (length/2)
    dark_area_result = math.pi * math.sqrt(radius)
    print ("Area of shaded region =","{:0.2f}".format(dark_area_result))

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that the canvas object attributes (outline and fill) cannot be separately overlapped by other objects. Either the object's fill and outline are overlapped (obscured) or not.

What is often done to manage your situation is to create a rectangle class that comprises both rectangles.

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, x0, y0, x1, y1):
        self.back = canvas.create_rectangle (x0, y0, x1, y1, fill="gray")
        self.outline = canvas.create_rectangle (x0, y0, x1, y1, outline="gray")

...
rectangle = Rectangle(win, 200,200, 300,300)
```

And then define a method for checking intersection of the Rectangle object to determine whether to raise the outline attribute above other widgets.